# Can't figure out this syntax error VBA SQL

Tags: sql, vba

I'm having an issue with Access. I'm trying to update one table (shipmentdata) with a few values from another table (customers). This is my code right now:

```
Option Compare Database

Sub Update()

Dim strSQL As String

strSQL = "UPDATE ShipmentData As A " & _
         "SET A.[Sales Rep] = B.[Sales Rep], A.OfficeNbr = B.OfficeNbr " & _
         "FROM A " & _
         "INNER JOIN Customers As B " & _
         "ON A.Owner = B.Name;"

DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL

End Sub
```

I keep getting an error: "Run-time error '3075': Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'B.OfficeNbr FROM A INNER JOIN Customers As B ON A.Owner = B.Name'.

I've tried it with/without aliases, with/without brackets in different places, I keep getting this error. Can someone help me please?

Comment: Without doing research and taking a shot in the dark: I think you forgot to include your "SELECT" in your inner select statement.

Comment: The right sintax of `UPDATE` doesn't include any `FROM`: `UPDATE aTable AS a INNER JOIN anotherTable AS b SET ... `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE ShipmentData A
INNER JOIN Customers B ON A.Owner = B.Name
SET A.[Sales Rep] = B.[Sales Rep], 
    A.OfficeNbr = B.OfficeNbr
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Worked like a charm. My syntax are bad.